# Change WP widget output depending on sidebar that is loading it

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

I'm learning WP as I go on this project so please bear with me.

I created a widget that displays a registration form for a hotel. This form will be loaded in different places of the site. Sometimes, it will load horizontally across a specific page, other times, as a sidebar in a narrow column.

The difference between the loading zone make me have to switch the output of the widget. There is information that I would like to leave out in one section but not in the other.

My initial thought was that there should be a way to identify where the widget was being called, and through that I could condition the output. In other words, in my widget, I would do something like this:

```
if (get_dynamic_sidebar() == "sidebar") {
    // display sidebar format
} elseif (get_dynamic_sidebar() == "footer") {
    // display horizontal format
}
```

Many hours of search have now brought me to believe that this option doesn't really exist, and I'm wondering what the best approach to solve my problem is.

Anyway, I'm quite flexible with the way I'll make this work, so all suggestions are welcome. All I want to avoid is having to create a new widget for this specific output.

Thanks so much.

Comment: As far as I know there is not a way for a widget to detect its own sidebar location. However a good alternative might be to add an option to your widget which you tick if it is to be displayed horizontally, this way you could differentiate between the two states in your widget code.

Comment: Thanks @rich. That's the kind of workaround I was looking for. I'll look into that. Thanks!